# How can I print javax.xml.validation.Schema?

Tags: java, xml, schema

I managed to generate an instance of `javax.xml.validation.Schema` from an instance of `JAXBContext`.

And how can I print it to the console?

```java
final javax.xml.validation.Schema schema = getSome();
// TODO: print schema to the console
```